# UML Tool to reverse engineer object diagrams from java source?

Tags: java, uml, object-diagram

I have been playing around with a few various UML tools- Enterprise Architect, Visual Paradigm; in the end I found Intellij IDEA good enough for producing quick UML class diagrams.

However, I found creating UML object diagrams quite fiddly in EA and VP.  I was wondering if there was anything out there that could reverse engineer some simple java code that creates some class instances - then create UML Object Diagrams from this?

Comment: Are you looking for free or paid tools?

Comment: Don't both EA and Vp do this - perhaps in a more expensive version

Comment: Years ago I used Rational to do this.  I'm not sure if RationalRose is still around though.  And it was quite expensive too.

Comment: EA is working fine for me. Did you have any problem with it?

Comment: Maybe I am not using VP Properly - I am trying the Professional eval edition - I just cant seem to find an option for Object diagrams.

Comment: I think I need to emphasize I am interested in Object diagrams - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram

Answer (score 3):

We use [UmlGraph](http://www.umlgraph.org/) embedded into a maven build, so we get graphs in the generated javadoc.

Comment: As far as I understand, you can't use UMLGraph to generate a diagram from Java code. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Jonathan It definitely works for me. Here's an example of how to set it up: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/alternate-doclet.html

Answer (score 1):

You should explore ObjectAid, it has an eclipse plugin as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for eclipse called [AmaterasUML](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasUML) that does a nice job on a hand full of source files.  It's not very useful for long term documentation but for quick and dirty "what's this package do?" it rocks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try Star UML.. its free and very easy to use..

http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 30 days evaluation licence and create all needed diagrams for documentation.
No need to purchase if you save diagrams as image and paste and copy them into your documentation. Just unzip and it works.

The build is available at: http://www.uml2.org/eclipse-java-galileo-SR2-win32_eclipseUML2.2_package_may2010.zip